# Last If statement ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My last `if` statement is ignored when executing.

When trying to debug I added `console.log` to the if statement and it functioned as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // set HTML
    var myVar = 'Null';
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501aa') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '01';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ab') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '02';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ac') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '03';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ad') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '04';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ae') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '05';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501af') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '06';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ag') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '07';
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ah') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '08';
        //console.log('myVar set to' + myVar);
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501aj') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '09';
        //console.log('myVar set to' + myVar);
    }
    else {
        setText();
    }
    function setText() {
        $('<label for="name">' + myVar + '</label>').insertBefore($('#name'));
    }
});
```

The [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L0a2g070/16/) isn't perfect due to the way they handle URLs.

How can I get the last if statement to return true and execute?

Comment: ot: Is this intended that the last ifs value ending with "j" instead of "i"?

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't exactly clear what your problem is.  What exactly happens that is different than you want to happen?

Comment: The last `if` statement does seem to work correctly if a propery indexOf is supplied. However, if the last if statement is true, `setText()` will not be called due to the `else`. Don't you want `setText()` to execute regardless of the `myVar` value? [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/L0a2g070/19/).

Comment: @showdev if you post an answer I will select it as correct.

Comment: Looks like you'd need `window.location.search` and an object instead of that bunch of code.

Comment: why is setText() in the else if the setText function uses myVar? See this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/uf3surmk/

Comment: @Teemu when is the proper use for `window.location.search` instead of `document.location.href.indexOf`?

Comment: @block14 rfornal beat me to it :)

Comment: When ever you need to extract the search string from an URL, it's very handy ; ).

Comment: location.search will return only the query string part of the url... so its just essentially changing the index, thats all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the `setText()` execution out of the conditional (else) portion of the if-structure; it is not running unless not value is 09, which makes it look like 09 is not working ...

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501aj') > -1 ) {
    myVar = '09';
    //console.log('myVar set to' + myVar);
}
setText();
```

Answer (score 4):

The original problem has already been explained by rfornal, but I thought I should mention that this code really needs to be DRYed up so there is no so much repeated code.  There are a couple ways to do it.

### Calculating the `myVar` result based on the character found:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var myVar = 'Null';
    var match = window.location.search.match(/1501a(?)/);
    if (match) {
        var chr = match[1].charAt(0);
        if (chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'h') {
            var code = match[1].charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1;
            myVar = '0' + code;
        } else if (char === 'j') {
            myVar = '09';
        }
    }
    $('<label for="name">' + myVar + '</label>').insertBefore($('#name'));
});
```

### And, here's a different way using a lookup table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var myVar = 'Null';
    var matches = {'1501aa': '01', '1501ab': '02', '1501ac': '03', '1501ad': '04', '1501ae': '05', 
       '1501af': '06', '1501ag': '07', '1501ah': '08', '1501aj': '09'};
    var match = window.location.search.match(/1501a?/);
    if (match) {
        var result = matches[match[0]];
        if (result) {
            myVar = result;
        }
    }
    $('<label for="name">' + myVar + '</label>').insertBefore($('#name'));
});
```

In addition, these also:

1. Use `window.location.search`
2. Get rid of the `setText()` function since it isn't needed, the single line of code can just be executed directly
3. Use a regex to find the match

Answer (score 1):

```
Wait what are we doing? I dunno here is this.  

    var myVar = "";

    fucker("02","ab");

    fucker("03","ac");

    //and so on

    $('<label for="name">' + myVar + '</label>').insertBefore($('#name'));

    function fucker(num,word) {
        if(document.location.href.indexOf("?1501"+word) > -1) {
            myVar = num;
        } 
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Very nice, but I don't think an alternate (arguably better) method helps the OP (or future readers) understand the problem. Maybe you could add some explanation?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. While I agree with @showdev that this doesn't help me understand the issue, I always do like to see a better solution to a problem.

Comment: I have no idea what the dude really wants lol. Like, I get it, but I don't at the same time. What I can tell OP is to be more efficient and chill out when doing some jqueery. Guy has an if else on the last if only. USE IF ELSE FOR ALL OF THEM EXCEPT THE LAST.

Comment: exactly. the current op code will always fire the else if it doesn't equal the last indexOf

Comment: @block14 The point is, that `else` "belongs" to the closest previous `if` only.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. Do you want it to set text after each one?

Comment: @Gretch I want the text to be set based on what the URL is. It should only be set once per page load.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different iteration using json, and looping.

```
//Function for setting the label
function setText(myVar) {
    $('<label for="name">' + myVar + '</label>').insertBefore($('#name'));
}

//used as the document.location.href
var url = "http://test.test.com?1501ad";
var myVar; //create the var but don't initialize it *note that creating myVar = 'Null'* does not create a null object. Though you don't need this. just overload the setText() 

//create an array of values as a json object
var urls = [{"url": "?1501ab", "myVar": "01"},
            {"url": "?1501ac", "myVar": "02"},
            {"url": "?1501ad", "myVar": "03"},
            {"url": "?1501ae", "myVar": "04"},
            {"url": "?1501af", "myVar": "05"},
            {"url": "?1501ag", "myVar": "06"},
            {"url": "?1501ah", "myVar": "07"},
           ];

//loop through and only set text when it finds the proper url ending test by adjusting the url variable.          
$.each(urls, function(key, value){
    if(url.indexOf(value.url) > -1){
        setText(value.myVar);
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/538t9bfk/

Comment: There's no JSON in your answer : (.

Answer (score -1):

Your if chain is strange. I would use else if, and then the final else will apply to all the if statements. right now your else only applies to the last if block.

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501aa') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '01';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ab') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '02';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ac') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '03';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ad') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '04';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ae') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '05';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501af') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '06';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ag') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '07';
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501ah') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '08';
        //console.log('myVar set to' + myVar);
    }
    else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('?1501aj') > -1 ) {
        myVar = '09';
        //console.log('myVar set to' + myVar);
    } else {
    //code what else you want to happen
}
setText();
```

Comment: Except `setText()` is where the value of `myVar` is used, so I rather doubt this is what the OP intends.

Comment: setText uses myVar so why is it in the else to begin with?

Comment: why mark it bad? i was using the code supplied. All i was saying is use else if instead of all if statements. it makes sense logically and is a more clear use.

Comment: for clarity since you guys can't read. I was saying the else only fired on the last if block. so if it matches any other condition along the way, that last else will still fire. i am sure that is not intended.

Comment: In your code, `setText()` won't be called unless `myVar` is NULL. I'm sure that's not intended either.

Comment: there i have updated my code to remove it out of the else, as that was copied from the dude that posted the question.